# Google tag assistant "No tags found" after switching <Script> strategy from "afterInteractive" to "worker" in Next JS

Tags: next.js, google-tag-manager, web-performance, partytown

I'm trying to optimize the below use of Google Tag Manager script in my Next Js application, and I came across this next/script strategy to load scripts called [worker](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/scripts#:%7E:text=browser%20idle%20time.-,worker,-%3A%20(experimental)%20Load%20the) which instantiate's partytown.

Based on Partytown's documentation ["Partytown is best suited for third-party scripts such as Google Tag Manager or Facebook Pixel, since they’re only handling user events and lazily posting data to their services in the background."](https://partytown.builder.io/trade-offs#:%7E:text=Partytown%20is%20best%20suited%20for%20third%2Dparty%20scripts%20such%20as%20Google%20Tag%20Manager%20or%20Facebook%20Pixel%2C%20since%20they%E2%80%99re%20only%20handling%20user%20events%20and%20lazily%20posting%20data%20to%20their%20services%20in%20the%20background.)

But when I use the strategy "worker", google tag assistant was not able to find my GTM tag. Please advice me on a workaround to find a way to make this work, or any other suggestions to avoid gtm blocking my main thread during intial page load.

I'm using the next/script tag in a HOC wrapper for all my websites pages. It was working fine with strategy="afterInteractive" and does not work now for "worker"

My current Next Js version: "~12.1.6",

Code when google tag assistant worked:

```
 {gtm && (
        <Script
          strategy="afterInteractive"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
            (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer', '${gtm}');
          `,
          }}
        />
      )}
```

Google tag assistant "No tags found" after changing strategy to worker:

```
 {gtm && (
        <Script
          strategy="worker"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
            (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer', '${gtm}');
          `,
          }}
        />
      )}
```

I tried using strategy="lazyOnload" and it is also resulting in "No tags found"